# Excel Column Help based on two columns for spitting containers

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to organize two columns. One would be numerical either in

- 1,2,3
- 1,1,2,2
  or
- 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
  with variants in numbering sometimes going like: 1,1,2,2,2,3,3

and then the second column would correspond as a dependent with like:

- 1A,2A,3A
- 1A,1B,2A,2B
  etc.

Is there an easier way for this? I tried to look online and there were various sequential formulas or integral ones but not fitting this case. Also, not very good with excel. I have been inputting it manually.

Answer (score 1):

If your column A items are sorted as you show, then

```
B1: =IF(A1="","",A1&CHAR(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)+64))
```

and fill down as far as needed

[image]

*Note: If you might have more than 25 repetitions, a different algorithm for generating the trailing letters will be needed, depending on what you might require*